# Android Wear OS - Detect When Arms Are Raised?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to detect when someone has raised their arms or is in a hanging position from their Wear OS watch?  Or figure out the orientation of their watch to figure out which edge is facing up or down?  Not sure if you can use one of the many sensors or a combination of them to detect this...

The Activity Recognition API doesn't seem to have a scenario I can capture, and I really can't think of another way to do it currently.